# Issue with npm nuxt3 build and Netlify

Tags: deployment, netlify, nuxtjs3

Hi I hope someone out there can help because I am completely lost and confused. I am a novice regarding hosting.

I have built a default Nuxt3 web site locally (ie ssr: ‘true’ and target:'server' i think).This is my nuxt.config.ts file:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'],
  runtimeConfig: {
    //this is a global data object to be used on every page to switch development on and off
    public: {myDev:false} 
  }
```

})

I ran npm run build locally with no errors.I then ran npm run start to see the site and all looked fine. I noticed npm run build created both a .nuxt/dist which contained a client and server folder and a .output folder which contained a public and server folder plus a nitro.jason file.
1-I don't understand what those folder are or what they contain.
2-Netlify allows you to drag your folder so they can host it but which one and why. What ever I tried it did not work.
3-I tried putting the whole site on github and linking a repository to netlify and it ran the script on netlify with no errors but when i tried to preview it it said file not found.
Hopefully someone can explain what is going on here?
Many thanks Neale